# Synchronous versions of a file in svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm looking for a way to have two synchronous versions of a source file in svn. It is simply about having additional comments (with a marker) in one file and not having them in another. For example, consider a file with this content:

```
// a comment
// <marker> some additional info
... code ...
```

I need to have a second version of this file which should look like this:

```
// a comment
... code ...
```

The simplest way I can get this second version is by running a post-processing (e.g. grep) on the file after it has been taken from the source control. However, this way any changes made to the file afterwards are difficult to merge back.

If I make a separate branch in svn for the second version, I know I'll have a lot of fun with manually merging changes back and forth, as there is no support for synchronous branches.

Is there a simple solution I missed? Could it be easier to achieve with another VCS such as git?

Comment: Can you give a little more details why you need such a thing or what's the intention or what you like to achieve with this?

Comment: @khmarbaise, it's complicated :) There is a separate repository (different VCS) where I shouldn't have those comments with the marker, but I find it convenient to have them for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Strip the additional info in your build process and only have 1 version in source control. As far as I know There exists no source control system which will allow this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not about the build process. If it was, I wouldn't even need to do anything as the difference is only in comments which do not affect build anyway.